# no viable alternative at character '%' in dynamic soql

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql, dynamic

I am creating this dynamic query and I am getting this error

```
String qry = '[Select id, name From selectedObject Where selectedField LIKE : '%' + userInput + '%' ]';
```

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a "dynamic" query. A dynamic query is one that has variable fields, objects, or filter conditions. Unless you have a strong, compelling reason, simply use an inline query:

```
SOject[] results = [Select id, name From selectedObject Where
                    selectedField LIKE :'%'+userInput+'%'];
```

Alternatively, you can use binding directly, but you'll have to modify your input string:

```
String selectedFieldValue = '%'+userInput+'%';
String query = 'SELECT Name FROM selectedObject WHERE '+
               'selectedField LIKE :selectedFieldValue';
```

This avoids the need to use String.escapeSingleQuotes, so the code is a bit more legible. There are restrictions on how bind expressions work in dynamic queries; the variable must be accessible to the current function, and must be a simple variable (i.e. not part of an array, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the reply the query worked, but I want to know 1 thing that I am selecting object dynamically from a picklist how could I hold selected object.I was using this query List<''+selectedObject> f = database.query(qry); its giving error

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced similar issue. can you please try this.

```
public String text = 'userinput'; //global variable

String localText = '%'+text+'%';//local variable 
string q= 'select id from account where name like :localText';
List<Account> accList = database.query(q);
system.debug('######### '+accList);
```

and remember if you copy paste query from internet to apex class, we will get this kind of issues. try to write a query instead of copy paste.

Comment: Is your answer the op copied and pasted and that was the reason for the error? If so you are incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove [ and ] from the query string.

You can try below code,

```
String userInput = 'test';
String strQuery = 'Select Id, Name from Account where Name LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(userInput.trim()) + '%\'';

List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>) Database.query(strQuery);

System.debug('###'+accountList);
```

Comment: userInput is an inputText where user will input text. I have a property from which I will get the value. if I hardcode str1 with value,  then how would I get the value from inputText

Comment: I have updated the code to use dynamix query, removed the (:) from the query as well.